# Add Signature to PDF

Tags: xml, pdf, digital-signature

I know there are already a lot of different threads about this topic, but I really couldn't find what I am looking for.

There is a service in my country which provides a digital signature for PDFs using a phone number and a password (you have to be registered for this service). Anyways, there is a WebService - which is very poorly documented - and I was able to use this service. After sending the request using my phone number and password, I receive the response for the digitital signature.

But the problem is that I don't receive the signed PDF, I just receive the original PDF, a X.509 certificate and a digest etc.

My question is, how can I add the digest and certificate to the PDF, so that the signature is recognized by common PDF readers?

Here is a short description of how the digital signature service is working:

1. I convert the PDF I want to sign to base64
2. I authenticate using my phone number and my password
3. the service returns the **unsigned** PDF and also a X.509 certificate and digest
4. I need to sign the PDF myself

I'm stuck at step 4.

Here is the `XMLResposne` of an example request using a test PDF (the digest and certificate are cut out):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sl:CreateXMLSignatureResponse xmlns:sl="...">
   <dsig:Signature xmlns:dsig="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Id="signature-1-1">
      <dsig:SignedInfo>
         <dsig:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
         <dsig:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#ecdsa-sha256" />
         <dsig:Reference Id="reference-1-1" URI="#signed-data-1-1">
            <dsig:Transforms>
               <dsig:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2002/06/xmldsig-filter2">
                  <xpf:XPath xmlns:xpf="http://www.w3.org/2002/06/xmldsig-filter2" Filter="intersect">id('signed-data-1-1')/node()</xpf:XPath>
               </dsig:Transform>
               <dsig:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#base64" />
            </dsig:Transforms>
            <dsig:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
            <dsig:DigestValue>[some digest]</dsig:DigestValue>
         </dsig:Reference>
         <dsig:Reference Id="etsi-data-reference-1-1" Type="http://uri.etsi.org/01903#SignedProperties" URI="#etsi-signedproperties-1-1">
            <dsig:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
            <dsig:DigestValue>[some digest]</dsig:DigestValue>
         </dsig:Reference>
      </dsig:SignedInfo>
      <dsig:SignatureValue Id="signaturevalue-1-1">[some base64 value]</dsig:SignatureValue>
      <dsig:KeyInfo>
         <dsig:X509Data>
            <dsig:X509Certificate>[some base64 value]</dsig:X509Certificate>
         </dsig:X509Data>
      </dsig:KeyInfo>
      <dsig:Object Id="signed-data-1-1">[the original PDF as base64, not signed]</dsig:Object>
      <dsig:Object Id="etsi-signed-1-1">
         <etsi:QualifyingProperties xmlns:etsi="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#" Target="#signature-1-1">
            <etsi:SignedProperties Id="etsi-signedproperties-1-1">
               <etsi:SignedSignatureProperties>
                  <etsi:SigningTime>2020-06-04T14:00:22Z</etsi:SigningTime>
                  <etsi:SigningCertificate>
                     <etsi:Cert>
                        <etsi:CertDigest>
                           <dsig:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
                           <dsig:DigestValue>[some digest]</dsig:DigestValue>
                        </etsi:CertDigest>
                        <etsi:IssuerSerial>
                           <dsig:X509IssuerName>[issuer name]</dsig:X509IssuerName>
                           <dsig:X509SerialNumber>[serial no]</dsig:X509SerialNumber>
                        </etsi:IssuerSerial>
                     </etsi:Cert>
                  </etsi:SigningCertificate>
                  <etsi:SignaturePolicyIdentifier>
                     <etsi:SignaturePolicyImplied />
                  </etsi:SignaturePolicyIdentifier>
               </etsi:SignedSignatureProperties>
               <etsi:SignedDataObjectProperties>
                  <etsi:DataObjectFormat ObjectReference="#reference-1-1">
                     <etsi:MimeType>application/pdf</etsi:MimeType>
                  </etsi:DataObjectFormat>
               </etsi:SignedDataObjectProperties>
            </etsi:SignedProperties>
         </etsi:QualifyingProperties>
      </dsig:Object>
   </dsig:Signature>
</sl:CreateXMLSignatureResponse>
```

Comment: That XML response looks like an enveloping XAdES signature of your PDF. This cannot be used to create an integrated PDF signature in your PDF.

Comment: Thanks! There is also a service to create a CMS signature. How is the "default" signature  called, that is also used in e.g. Adobe Acrobat etc.?

Comment: The standard PDF signature is defined in ISO 32000 and ISO 19905. Additionally there is [PAdES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PAdES).

Comment: If you do some programming around the call of the CMS signature service, you may be able to use it to create integrated pdf signatures. Please share an example signature from the CMS signing service and explain which pdf signature profile you need.